# Can GTM custom html be inserted with id of some sort

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Can GTM custom html be deliver to page with some sort of identifier? I want to make automated tests to see is it appeared and I don't want to put some other type of identifier inside code.

Looking at page source all script tags are delivered without id.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following the snippet that appears on the Google tag manager page you can modify it to make sure that when is inserted it adds the attribute id to the script element with the value you want.

this is default the Google tag manager snippet:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

And this is how you can customize it to make sure that uses an ID:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i,customID){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;j.setAttribute('id', customID );f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX', 'tagManagerID' );</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

You just need to add the tag manager id at the bottom where are defined all the values, and later when the script is being created (variable j) we set the attribute id with the customID variable (the tag manager ID).

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, what I want to achieve is to differentiate from different tags and test appearance of different tags and make sure it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain it a bit more what you are trying to do with GTM? Usually we can populate Snippet variables to our liking without touching the actual Google Tag Manager Code.

Answer (score 0):

Ante, you should take a look at the debug feature of GTM, I think this is waht you are looking for.

Comment: Can it be activated automatically?

Comment: No you have to activate it manually, read https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2695660?hl=en (be sure about the version of gtm you are using)